# JQGrid and JSON data from Web2py

Tags: json, jqgrid, web2py

Q1.json is working (index.json). but i cant display in the jqgrid. i think colmodel names is the problem.Is it required that the colModel name is from database field? i want to display in jqgrid is from my select statements and those variables is from different tables. Not only one table but 3 tables.

Q2.Same row should be displayed in jqgrid but from different table. is it possible?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
  jQuery("#list").jqGrid({

    url:'{{=URL(r=request,f='call',args=['json','index'])}}',
      data: "{}",
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'GET',
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      complete: function(jsondata, stat) {
        if (stat == "success") {
            var thegrid = jQuery("#list")[0];
            thegrid.addJSONData(JSON.parse(jsondata.responseText).d);
        }
    }, 
    colNames:['code','name','max','min','quantity','amount'],
    colModel :[ 
      {name:CODE',index:'CODE', width:55}, 
      {name:'Name', index:'Name',width:100}, 
      {name:'MAX(table2.hour)', index:'MAX(hour)',width:100},
      {name:'MIN(tabl2.hour)', index:'MIN(hour)',width:100}, 
      {name:'SUM(quantity)', index:'SUM(quantity)',width:180}, 
      {name:'SUM(amount)', index:'SUM(amount)',width:180}
    ],
    hidegrid: false,
    scrollOffset:0,
    pager: '#pager',
    rowNum:100,
    shrinkToFit:false,
    //rowList:[10,20,30,50],
    //sortname: 'id',
   //sortorder: 'desc',
    viewrecords: false,
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    caption: 'SALES Grid'
  }); 


}); 
</script>
```

{"rows": [0, {"table1": {"Name": "dyon"}, "_extra": {"MAX(table2.hour)": "20130514214301484", "MIN(table2.hour)": "20130514052610093", "SUM(table2.quantity)": 2115.854, "SUM(table2.amount)": 90089.15}, "table3": {"CODE": 1800}}]}

NOTE: i want to display the data in one page only.when i run the index.html it contains rows but it is blank and theres a rows contains 0 per cell.When i run the index.json it contains the data i needed. Im newbie to python. thanks!

Comment: You wrote that the server returns JSON data, but don't post the example of the data. You wrote that you suppose that you have problem in `colModel`, but not post the `colModel` too. It's not important which database field has the database table, it's important which data you returns in JSON response from the server. Could you append the text of your question with JavaScript code which create jqGrid and with example of JSON response. You can use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/get-fiddler), [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/)  or Developer Tools of IE/Chrome to catch full HTTP traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is that you use many options of jqGrid which not exist (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options)): `data`, `contentType`, `complete`. You remove the options or use some other options which do what you probably tried to do.

The second problem is the usage of properties in JSON input which has dots inside (like `SUM(table2.quantity)` for example). To be able to read such properties you have to define `jsonmap` as function. For example

```css
jsonmap: function (obj) {
    return obj._extra["SUM(table2.quantity)"];
}
```

Because the JSON data have `0` as the first element you will have to fix the above code to somthing like

```
jsonmap: function (obj) {
    return typeof obj === "object"? obj._extra["SUM(table2.quantity)"]: "";
}
```

[The first demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CrazyGirl0.htm) demonstrate the results:

[image]

The best would be to fix your server code to remove the unneeded `0` item from `rows` array. If you can't do this on the server side you can do this on the client side inside of `beforeProcessing` callback.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CrazyGirl.htm) displays

[image]

It uses the following JavaScript code

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
    url: "CrazyGirl.json", // need be changed to youth
    datatype: "json",
    ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
    serializeGridData: function (data) {
        return JSON.stringify({}); // send empty object (???)
    },
    colNames: ["code", "name", "max", "min", "quantity", "amount"],
    colModel: [
        {name: "code", width: 55, jsonmap: "table3.CODE"},
        {name: "name", width: 100, jsonmap: "table1.Name"},
        {name: "max", width: 120,
            jsonmap: function (obj) {
                return typeof obj === "object"? obj._extra["MAX(table2.hour)"]: "";
            }},
        {name: "min", width: 120,
            jsonmap: function (obj) {
                return typeof obj === "object"? obj._extra["MIN(table2.hour)"]: "";
            }},
        {name: "quantity", width: 100,
            jsonmap: function (obj) {
                return typeof obj === "object"? obj._extra["SUM(table2.quantity)"]: "";
            }},
        {name: "amount", width: 100,
            jsonmap: function (obj) {
                return typeof obj === "object"? obj._extra["SUM(table2.amount)"]: "";
            }}
    ],
    jsonReader: { repeatitems: false },
    hidegrid: false,
    pager: "#pager",
    rowNum: 1000,
    shrinkToFit: false,
    height: "100%",
    caption: "SALES Grid"
  });
```

Comment: hi oleg! it works! but i didn't use it for some change. I helps me to understand about jqgrid. You are great! thanks!