# Get the Values from one ColModel,perform Math operation and apply the values to other ColModel

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

Like am having situation where i have Dates in one colModel and i need to perform Math Operation(Subtract) with the current Date and Display it in the other colModel json in jQgrid,

```
{name:'createdOn',hidden:true, width:80, sortable:true,editable: false,sorttype:'date', formatter:'date',formatoptions:{ srcformat: 'M d y H:i:s', newformat: 'd M y h:i A'},resizable:false}
```

can it be done in gridComplete or loadComplete.?

Thanks in advance.!

Answer (score 0):

The usage of `gridComplete` or `loadComplete` to *modify* the grid is not the best way. Every kind of  modification of elements on HTML page is relatively expensive (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12519858/315935) for details). The most effective way to implement your requirements would be to *create* the grid with correct values for all column. To do this I would recommend you to use one from two approaches:

- use `jsonmap` defined as function for the column which need to have results of Math Operation. If you define `jsonmap` as function with one parameter your callback function will get the item which represent the row of input data. You callback function `jsonmap` need just returns the value for the column which can be calculated based on the values of other columns. I'm sure you will find many examples of usage `jsonmap` as function in my old answers on the stackoverflow. For example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10731526/315935), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8150904/315935), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6904980/315935), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17876777/315935) and many other.
- modify input data for the grid returned from the server *before* the data will be processed by jqGrid. You can use `beforeProcessing` callback to "pre-process" the data. Examples of the usage of `beforeProcessing` you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9855764/315935), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9867370/315935), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17410568/315935), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9722466/315935), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9667067/315935) and many other.